# Swift инициализация массива двойной вложенности

Tags: массивы, swift

Есть переменная

```
var test : [[String]]
```

Не подскажите, как ее можно сразу инициализировать задав сразу необходимую длину?
Очень не хочется каждый раз делать append-ы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test : [[String]] = [[String]](count: 10, repeatedValue: [String](count: 10, repeatedValue: "Temp value"))
```

Comment: Данных еще нет. Я знаю только размер. Данные будут позже получаться. Мне нужно только инициализировать с указанием размере аналогично var a : [String] = [String](count : 10, repeatedValue: "")

Comment: поменял, глянь - подходит?

Comment: Да, спасибо! Столько разных вариантов перепробовал, а вот до этого не додумался :(